# Python code coverage for server code when using external test client

Tags: python, pytest-cov

I have a python API server (server.py) that calls my python library (api/feature1.py, api/feature2.py etc). I have an external client running on a different machine which will invoke a bunch of requests to test for responses.

I want to get the coverage of all the code in api/ directory. Does pytest-cov help here and if yes, how to I use it? I have used it unit-tests with mock objects etc and my requirement seems different.

Comment: You could, check the package and documentation of pytest-cov
`For distributed testing support install pytest-xdist` 
https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xdist.html